# Multiple rails apps on single IP (nginx + passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm looking for the way to serve multiple rails apps on one server. I uploaded one of the apps and it works just fine. But as soon as I create nginx configuration for a new app, it crashes first one.
I can't find an appropriate guide for this. If you have any advice, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can surely help you with reverse proxy as well as serving multiple apps:

https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try it asap.

Comment: I have some progress but stuck again. Would be appreciated for another advice. The question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826496/multiple-rails-apps-nginx-passenger-config