# Multiple rails apps nginx passenger config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I used [this](https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0) guide to setup server.

Here are my configs:

**nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 
application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss 
text/javascript;

##
# Phusion Passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
##

#include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

**nginx/mysite1**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name mysite1.com;

    client_max_body_size 75m;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite1.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite1.error.log;

        root         /home/deploy/www/mysite1/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }


}
```

**nginx/mysite2**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name mysite2.com;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite2.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite2.error.log;

        root         /home/deploy/www/mysite2/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8181;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

mysite1 is working fine, but when I go to mysite2, I see mysite1.
I think the passenger is ok, cause I have passenger.8080.pid and passenger.8181.pid in direcories mysite1 and mysite2, respectively.
Run out of ideas, so asking for help.

Comment: If IPv6 is used by client (browser), than you will see mysite1, because listen with v6 address commented out in mysite2 server block.

Comment: Thanks, @citrin, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

So, the reason why I stuck is ... comma!
Somehow I separated domains with a comma. That is it.

Comment: I have this same problem.  What "comma" did you fix to solve it??