# Serving the same Rails application with different ENV variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to serve the same Rails application with different ENV variables on different ports, i.e.

- port 443 with BRAND_SPACE set to "default"
- port 444 with BRAND_SPACE set to "somethingelse"

This particular ENV variable affects the styling of the application (think multi tenant) and I want to be able to check the same application with both stylings.

I have the following setup with nginx+Passenger (shortened for readability):

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
    passenger_max_pool_size 8;
    passenger_max_instances_per_app 4;
    passenger_max_requests 500;
    passenger_show_version_in_header off;

    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name staging.example.de;
        root /apps/staging/example/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env staging;
        passenger_env_var BRAND_SPACE default;
    }

    server {
        listen 444;
        server_name staging.example.de;
        root /apps/staging/example/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env staging;
        passenger_env_var BRAND_SPACE somethingelse;
    }
}
```

What now happens is that the ENV variable of the app that was first requested after a restart is used for both applications, i.e. if you request the app on 443 first, then the ENV variable "default" will also be set for the app on 444.

Am I using the configuration wrong or should this be solved in a different way? If so, I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I think this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44774262/2644894
And this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826496/multiple-rails-apps-nginx-passenger-config

Comment: I don't really see where this is helpful for the described issue. This seems to have more to do with Passenger than with nginx - the configuration is working fine like it is and the app is served properly (aside from the ENV issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue reappeared again and I finally found an answer:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_app_group_name

Setting this variable will allow you to serve the same application, with the same root under two different domains or server blocks.